# Which languages do I need to learn to be able to program an extension

Tags: web, background, automation, extract

I am looking forward to program an extension for Google Chrome which runs in background and extracts information from a site. If a specific value of information equals my search parameters it should start performing some automated actions and then going back to the information-extraction loop.

Tl;DR
Language that can:
*automate web routines
*extract information
*running in background

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Using `css`, `js` and `html` as you do to make a website.

Look at this webpage: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: I've been thinking about using jsoup because I already have some knowledge in js and I would also like to let the setup run on my RaspberryPi later on, but I don't know how I should approach it. And it should constantly refresh the page and check for new values in the background...